# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 automatically adding rows and cols attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, textarea

We have some code that calls the `Html.TextArea(string name, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)` extension method.  This method is adding `rows="2" cols="20"` automatically.  I see in Reflector that these are internal values (part of an `implicitRowsAndColumns` dictionary).

Is there a way to force ASP.NET MVC to not output these attributes? I don't understand why their code would do this in the first place since CSS is a much better way to establish the size of a `textarea`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `new { rows = "", cols = "" }` to your `TextAreaFor` call.

It is likely because validators require the rows and cols attributes. But just because they are required does not mean they need to have a value.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/2649283/avoid-textarea-rows-cols-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649283/avoid-textarea-rows-cols-error)

Comment: I bet the resizer here would remove them. But then you have different problem. stackoverflow.com/questions/5893171/html-textareafor-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Wow, so those attribute are actually required for some doctypes!? Seriously dumb.

Comment: did not mean to have the 20,10 in there. I meant for rows and cols to be empty strings

Comment: Yeah.it is not too far off of adding width and height on img tags to save on reflows though. Sometimes it pays to give the rendering engine some hints

Comment: Empty strings caused the original numbers to still show, as did zeroes.  Oh well, at least I know why it happens now.  I can just use CSS to resize, making those numbers meaningless in most cases.